# Programmatically created ScrollView is not working

Tags: swift

i still don't get the hang of `UIScrollView`...
i want to create one add it to a container and add a StackView to it:

```
let scroll = UIScrollView()
scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackWidth, height: stackHeight)
bottomContainer.addSubview(scroll)
let stack = UIStackView()
stack.axis = .horizontal
stack.alignment = .center
stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
scroll.addSubview(stack)
stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.topAnchor, constant: 25),
    scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
    scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.leadingAnchor),
    scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.trailingAnchor),
    scroll.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth),
    scroll.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth),
    stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor),
    stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.bottomAnchor),
    stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
    stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth),
    ])
```

`bottomContainer` is created in Storyboard.
`stackHeight` is calculated to be 50 less than the height of `bottomContainer` and `stackWidth` is variable but even if gets greater than the `bottomContainer` it doesn't scroll. Thanks for any help

Comment: your question is very unclear will you please check it

Comment: The problem is that the stack view is empty. So there is no content to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

let scroll = UIScrollView()
scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

let stack = UIStackView()
stack.axis = .horizontal
stack.alignment = .center
stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
scroll.addSubview(stack)
stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.topAnchor, constant: 25),
    scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
    scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.leadingAnchor),
    scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.trailingAnchor),
    scroll.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth),
    scroll.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth),
    stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor),
    stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.bottomAnchor),
    stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
    stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth),
    ])
scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackWidth, height: stackHeight)
bottomContainer.addSubview(scroll)
```